# JAXB with Generified @XmlElement

Tags: generics, jaxb, schema, jaxb2

I have an abstract class looks like this.

```java
@XmlTrasient
public abstract class SimpleValue<R> {

    public R getRawValue() {
        return rawValue;
    }

    public void setRawValue(final R rawValue) {
        this.rawValue = rawValue;
    }

    @XmlElement(nillable = true, required = true)
    private R rawValue;
}
```

And I extended with this one.

```java
public class BooleanValue extends SimpleValue<Boolean> {
}
```

When I printed the schema I got this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
           targetNamespace="http://jinahya.googlecode.com/xml/bind"
           xmlns:tns="http://jinahya.googlecode.com/xml/bind"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="booleanValue" type="tns:booleanValue"/>

  <xs:complexType name="booleanValue">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="rawValue" type="xs:anyType" nillable="true"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Is there any way to express `type="xs:anyType"` part more nicely?

When I redundantly override following two methods with `BooleanValue`

```java
@XmlElement(nillable = true, required = true)
@Override
public Boolean getRawValue() {
    return super.getRawValue();
}

@Override
public void setRawValue(final Boolean rawValue) {
    super.setRawValue(rawValue);
}
```

I got.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
           targetNamespace="http://jinahya.googlecode.com/xml/bind"
           xmlns:tns="http://jinahya.googlecode.com/xml/bind"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="booleanValue" type="tns:booleanValue"/>

  <xs:complexType name="booleanValue">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="rawValue" type="xs:boolean" nillable="true"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is what you have posted in your question.

```java
@XmlElement(nillable = true, required = true)
@Override
public Boolean getRawValue() {
    return super.getRawValue();
}

@Override
public void setRawValue(final Boolean rawValue) {
    super.setRawValue(rawValue);
}
```

Comment: 透彻 [tòuchè]. I Think there may be some `lax=true` or something. Thanks.